# Mark point Google maps custom script

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have my custom script for map into my webpage,but it no have point mark for exactly ubication:

```
<script>
/* Map */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    if (document.getElementById("map")) {
        var locations = [
            ['<div class="map-info-box"><ul class="contact-info-list"><li><span><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></span> Mimar Sinan Mh., Konak/İzmir, Türkiye</li><li><span><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i></span> +90 0 (232) 324 11 83</li></ul></div>', 38.396652, 27.090560, 9]
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.0961599, -110.96087460000001),
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [{ "featureType": "all", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 }, { "gamma": 0.5 }] }]
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: 'images/pin.png',
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }

}());
```

So I need to add markpoint like default embed map http://www.map-embed.com/:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;">
<div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
<style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}    </style>
<a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.themecircle.net" id="get-map-data">www.themecircle.net</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:13,center:new     google.maps.LatLng(29.0961599,-110.96087460000001),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new    google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(29.0961599, -110.96087460000001)});
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>Minerals</b><br/>Reyes #100<br/>83190 Hermosillo" });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
    infowindow.open(map,marker);}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

How can I that my marker appears like default map?
Your answers are very apreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the marker declaration inside the ***initMap()*** function to put a default marker at a particular coordinate when a map is loaded. Here is the HTML + Javascript code from the official Google documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more details follow this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this it work for me.

add this div on html page where you want to show your map

```
<div class="google-map-canvas" id="map-canvas"></div>
```

and add this script also...

```
function initialize() {
    // Change the latitude and longitude to your location. You can also get the coordinates here: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.548710, 82.084777);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:
            '<div class="map-wrap">' +
                // Company name
                '<div class="b-title">' + 'Company Name' + '</div>' +
                // Company street
                '<p>' + 'Company Street' + '</p>' +
                // Company city and state
                '<p>' + 'Company City and State' + '</p>' +
                // Clearfix with border
                '<div class="clrfx map-div">' + '</div>' +
                // Row 1
                '<div class="row">' +
                    // Phone
                    '<div class="b-info cell w-49">' + '<span class="entypo-phone">' + '</span>' + '+91-879-902-1616' + '</div>' +
                    // Email
                    '<div class="b-info cell w-49">' + '<span class="entypo-paper-plane">' + '</span>' + 'example@example.com' + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                // Row 2
                '<div class="row">' +
                    // Mobile
                    '<div class="b-info cell w-49">' + '<span class="entypo-mobile">' + '</span>' + '+91-879-902-1616' + '</div>' +
                    // Website
                    '<div class="b-info cell w-49">' + '<span class="entypo-monitor">' + '</span>' + 'www.example.com' + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                // Bottom margin clearfix
                '<div class="clrfx mt-10">' + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    });
    makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker);
}

function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```